# Java - Remote file browser

Tags: java, file

I've made some searches but I've found nothing about that.

I plan to make a full remote tool for my server coded in java. I have successfully made the part to send a file to the server but now I want to use a file browser to list and get all files. I know how to make a local jFileChooser but is it possible to make it remote?

I connect to my server with a socket.

Thanks.

Comment: not sure why you would need this and may be you should look at your design. However, you can try opening a ssh/ sftp connection and running ls over it. You can then stream the output into custom swing components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone actually already made what you are trying and hosted that on sourceforge. You can get the source code too. Check [vfsjfilechooser](http://vfsjfilechooser.sourceforge.net)

To get a comparison of vjsfilechooser methods and JFileChooser API you can read through the url mentioned below.
http://www.loni.ucla.edu/twiki/bin/view/CCB/VFSBrowserProgrammersGuide?skin=plain&sortcol=1&table=1&up=1

Answer (score 1):

I don't imagine you can configure JFileChooser to be remote but you should be able to write your own based on its code or even sub-class it.

If you are going to write a look-a-like the Windows file chooser is generally considered to be nicer.

You could base it on VFS or similar so it can work with any filesystem.

Comment: *"should be able to write your own "*  To create the GUI side of it, you might start with the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) though note that it also is designed for files on the local file-system.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its a web based application , you want to select a file from the application server. Check if that is really a good option , because i can get a clear view and idea of the server file structure. There would be definitely a security threat.

Answer (score 0):

```
package learnings;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

public class SimpleLinuxGUI {

String sshremotedir = "GiveRemoteDirectoryPath";
public static void cargarRTree(String remotePath, DefaultMutableTreeNode parent) throws SftpException, JSchException { 
//todo: change "/" por remote file.separator
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = null;
session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setPassword(password);
session.connect();
Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
channel.connect();
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = sftpChannel.ls(remotePath); // List source directory structure.
    System.out.println(list);
//Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = sftpChannel
for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry oListItem : list) { // Iterate objects in the list to get file/folder names.       
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(oListItem.getFilename());
    if (!oListItem.getAttrs().isDir()) { // If it is a file (not a directory).
        parent.add(node); // add as a child node
    } else{
        if (!".".equals(oListItem.getFilename()) && !"..".equals(oListItem.getFilename())) {
            parent.add(node); // add as a child node
            cargarRTree(remotePath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename(), node); // call again for the subdirectory
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleLinuxGUI slg = new SimpleLinuxGUI();
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();


    DefaultMutableTreeNode nroot = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(slg.sshremotedir);                
    try {
        cargarRTree(slg.sshremotedir, nroot);
    } catch (SftpException e1) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }       catch (JSchException ex) { 
        Logger.getLogger(SimpleLinuxGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 
    JTree yourJTree = new JTree(nroot);
    jf.add(yourJTree);
    jf.setSize(640, 480);
    jf.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

This Code will help you to Get the list of files and directories in Remote server then creates a Jtree and Display in GUI.And now You can make changes to GUI  by adding action listeners and adding buttons to achieve your requirements